# How do i specify a file location in terminal?

Tags: command-line, filemanager, paths

Running the following commands:

```
wine /Home/Downloads/steamsetup.exe
wine Username/Home/downloads/steamsetup.exe
```

resulted in `file not found`. How do I specify a file location in terminal?

I am on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Comment: It is `/home/username/` or `~`

Comment: See the wiki: [Using The Terminal - File & Directory Commands](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#File_.26_Directory_Commands)

Answer (score 1):

try

```
wine ~/Downloads/steamsetup.exe
```

The '~' character is replaced by current user home directory.

Comment: @BaileyJohnston If you type in `echo ~` at a terminal prompt, it will show you the home folder full path.

Comment: It is /home/username not just /home

Comment: what about files that use ctrl + h?

Comment: As far as I know CTRL + h (^h) in standard Linux terminal is interpreted as `backspace` character.